# How to navigate from UIWindow To UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iphone application which is having a UIWindow. I want to add more UIViews to that.
I tried this.

```
SettingsViewController *viewctrl = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewctrl animated:YES];
[viewctrl release];
```

But it didnt worked. Anybody please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if your `self.navigationController` is not `nil` first.

Comment: how does it not work. is there an error, what happens?

Comment: i have put 
NSLog(@"SettingsPressed"); which is executing.
But not going to next view

Comment: Currently my application is showing MainWindow.xib.. Its not in UIviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show more code.
self.navigationController is nil by default if you didn't setup a navigation controller.

Comment: When my application launches, My MainWindow.xib loads. I want to navigate a uiviewcontroller when i clicked on UIBarButtonItem. So am calling a function - (IBAction) SettingsPressed: (id) sender{}. I have added
 IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
in my Appdelegate.h 

- (IBAction) SettingsPressed: (id) sender{......}
This function is written above